# AJAX Success Return Repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, upload

I have a form to upload a profile icon image. Once the upload is complete on AJAX success, I grab the new image path and display the image. It works fine, however, if I used the script several times without refreshing the page, the new returned image flashes several times after its dynamically loaded. (See gif animation).

This repeat ‘flashing’ of the returned image seems to increase if I continue to used the script without a page refresh. So, I am guessing I’m doing something wrong here. Missing something to prevent the event from continuing to fire? Also, If I do encounter an error, the error alert also fires/repeats many times.

[image]

```
$('#image_icon').change(function() { 
    $('#icon_upload_form').submit();
});

$('#icon_upload_form').on('submit',(function(e) {
        
        var icon_loader = $(".icon_loader").show();
        
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '../process/process_icon_upload.php',
            data:formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType   : "json",
            success:function(data){

                icon_loader.hide();

                if (data.error > 0) {
                    
                    alert(data.msg)
                    
                } else if (data.error == 0) {
                    $("#save_map_icon").fadeIn("fast");
                    $("#new_map_icon").css({"background-image":"url('../images_icons_tmp/"+data.filename+"')"})
                }
                
                return false;
                
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert("Error - "+JSON.stringify(data))
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
                return false;
            }
        });
    
    })
)
```

Comment: try adding  `$("#save_map_icon").stop()` after `$("#save_map_icon").fadeIn("fast");`

Comment: I am guessing you are binding events more than once.

Comment: @epascarello - How would I trouble shoot that? I tried $('#icon_upload_form').off('submit').on('submit',(function(e) {... AND tried adding  $(this).unbind('submit') to the end of `success`. didn't work

Comment: `console.log("binding change"); $('#image_icon').change(function() { console.log('change fired'); $('#icon_upload_form').submit(); });` and add one to the submit code. See if you see them triggered more than once.

Comment: Ok yes thats exactly what is going on 
[Log] binding change on submit (worldmap.php, line 166, x2)
[Log] change fired (worldmap.php, line 159)
[Log] binding change on submit (worldmap.php, line 166, x2)
[Log] change fired (worldmap.php, line 159)

I should have been more clear in my question too; the whole image select and upload page is also dynamically loaded over the top of the current page. When I close that dynamic page overlay and then reopen it to upload a new image, im getting the multiple events firing - exponentially with each new upload. 

How would I combat this?

Comment: Now that I think about it - that new upload page overlay has the JS embedded on the page, so its obviously loading multiple times with each new upload?

Comment: @epascarello - I worked it out. I moved the JS to its own file and change the dynamic code to $('body').on('change', '#image_icon', function() { .. and it works great. Thanks a lot for your help!